# How to Combine CSV Files with Pandas (And Add Identifying Column)

Tags: python, csv, pandas

How do I add multiple CSV files together and an extra column to indicate where each file came from?

So far I have:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

os.chdir('C:\...')  # path to folder where all CSVs are stored
for f, i in zip(glob.glob('*.csv'), short_list):
   df = pd.read_csv(f, header = None)
   df.index = i * len(df) 
   dfs.append(df)

all_data = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```

It all works well, except for the identifying column. `i` is a list of `strings` that I want to put in column A of `all_data`. One string for every row of each column. Instead it returns a lot of numbers, and gives a `TypeError: Index(....) must be called witha  collection of some kind`.

Expected output:

```
str1 file1entry1
str1 file1entry2
str1 file1entry3
str2 file2entry1
str2 file2entry2
str2 file2entry3
```

Where `short_list = ['str1', 'str2', 'str3']`, and `file1entery1, file2entry2... etc` comes from the CSV files I already have.

Solution:
I wasn't able to get it all in one line like the solution suggested, however it pointed me in the right direction.

```
for f zip(glob.glob('*csv')):
    df = pd.read_csv(f, header = None)
    df = df.assign(id = os.path.basename(f)) # simpler than pulling from the array. Adds file name to each line. 
    dfs.append(df)

all_data = pd.concat(dfs)
```

Comment: No need to use `* len(df)`. When assigning a scalar to new column, value is applied to every row.

Comment: Note that you don't actually need to use Pandas here. You could simply use the `csv` module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [.assign(id=i)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) method, which will add `id` column to each parsed CSV and will populate it with the `i` value:

```
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, header = None).assign(id=i)
                for f, i in zip(glob.glob('*.csv), short_list)],
               ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Wanted to respond to your comment. `str1, str2, str3` are stored in `short_list`. Typo.